# Tic Tac Toe in C

Tags: c, game, tic-tac-toe

I implemented a version of the popular Tic Tac Toe game. It currently only supports two-player mode, but I'm planning to add artificial intelligence for user vs computer mode (which I don't know how, yet).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cmdio.h" /* this defines getnum, yesno and select_menu */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} BoardPosition;

typedef enum {
    NONE = 0,
    USER,
    COMP
} PlayerType;

typedef struct {
    PlayerType type;
    char symbol;
} Player;

typedef enum {
    HORIZONTAL = 0,
    VERTICAL,
    L_DIAGONAL,
    R_DIAGONAL
} WinMethod;

typedef struct {
    Player *player;
    WinMethod method;
} Winner;

typedef char Board[3][3];

/* interactive functions */
static void print_board(Board *);
static BoardPosition get_pos(Board *);

/* utility functions */
static void update_board(Board *, const BoardPosition, const Player *);
static Winner who_won(Board *, Player *, Player *);
static size_t count_board(Board *);
static void play_turn(Board *, Player *);

int main(void)
{
    Player player1 = { USER,  'X'};
    Player player2 = { USER, 'O' };
    /* The winner, for now. */
    Winner winner = { NULL /* none */,  0 /* whatever */};
    /* settle on configuration */
    puts("I want to play as ..");
    /* select_menu returns the index of the option the user chose */
    if (select_menu( (const char *[]) { "X", "O" }, 2, "> " )) {
        /* switch symbols */
        player1.symbol = 'O';
        player2.symbol = 'X';
    }
    puts("I want to play with ..");
    if (select_menu( (const char *[]) { "User", "Computer" }, 2, "> " ))
        player2.type = COMP;
    /* initializing the board */
    Board brd;
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
            brd[x][y] = 0;

    Player *player = &player1;
    for (;;) {
        /* print board */
        print_board(&brd);
        /* demand a position to fill */
        printf("Player %d's turn ..\n", (player == &player1) ? 1 : 2);
        play_turn(&brd, player);
        /* check for win */
        winner = who_won(&brd, &player1, &player2);
        if (winner.player == NULL) { /* no one won */
            /* check for draw */
            if (count_board(&brd) == 9) {
                puts("Draw!");
                return 0;
            }
            /* switch turns */
            player = (player == &player1) ? &player2 : &player1;
        } else if (winner.player == &player1) { /* player1 won */
            if (player1.type == COMP)
                puts("Oh! You lost .. Nevermind ... You'll win next time!");
            else
                puts("Congratulations! Player 1 won!");
            return 0;
        } else { /* player2 won */
            if (player2.type == COMP)
                puts("Oh! You lost .. Nevermind ... You'll win next time!");
            else
                puts("Congratulations! Player 2 won!");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    /* should never be reached */
    fputs("Internal Error!", stderr);
    return 1;
}

static Winner who_won(brd, player1, player2)
    Board *brd;
    Player *player1, *player2;
{
    int stat1 = 1;
    int stat2 = 1;

    // check horizontal, then vertical
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
                stat1 &= ((*brd)[i ? x : y][i ? y : x] == player1->symbol);
                stat2 &= ((*brd)[i ? x : y][i ? y : x] == player2->symbol);
            }
            if (stat1)
                return (Winner){player1, i};
            if (stat2)
                return (Winner){player2, i};
            stat1 = 1;
            stat2 = 1;
        }
    }

    // check left diagonal, then right diagonal
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int d = (i ? 0 : 2); i ? (d < 3) : (d >= 0); i ? (++d) : (--d)) {
            stat1 &= ((*brd)[d][d] == player1->symbol);
            stat2 &= ((*brd)[d][d] == player2->symbol);
        }
        if (stat1)
            return (Winner){player1, i + 2};
        if (stat2)
            return (Winner){player2, i + 2};

        stat1 = 1;
        stat2 = 1;
    }
    return (Winner){NULL, 0};
}

static void print_board(brd)
    Board *brd;
{
    char start = '1';
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
            if ((*brd)[x][y])
                printf("%c", (*brd)[x][y]);
            else
                printf("%c", start);
            if (y < 2)
                printf(" | ");
            else
                printf("\n");
            start += sizeof(char);
        }
    }
}

static BoardPosition get_pos(brd)
    Board *brd;
{
    BoardPosition pos;
    int p;
    while (1) {
        getnum(stdin, "Enter position: ", 1, 9, (long long *) &p);
        /* determine real position */
        int i = 0;
        for (pos.x = 0; pos.x < 3; ++pos.x)
            for (pos.y = 0; pos.y < 3; ++pos.y)
                if (++i == p && !(*brd)[pos.x][pos.y])
                    return pos;
        puts("Please provide an available position.");
    }
    return pos;
}

static void update_board(brd, pos, player)
    Board *brd;
    const BoardPosition pos;
    const Player *player;
{
    if (!player->type)
        return;
    (*brd)[pos.x][pos.y] = player->symbol;
}

static size_t count_board(brd)
    Board *brd;
{
    size_t count;
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
            count += !!(*brd)[x][y];
    return count;
}

static void play_turn(brd, player)
    Board *brd;
    Player *player;
{
    if (player->type == USER) {
        update_board(brd, get_pos(brd), player);
    } else {
        /* TODO: add artificial intelligence */
        fputs("Artificial Intelligence not yet implemented\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Well, what do you think?

Comment: *Use the right tool for the right job.* C is for: Low-level hardware control, Heavy number chrunching, Microprocesssors. Implementing Tic-Tac-Toe is a task you should do in a high level programming language.

Comment: @Caridorc: Actually, I wrote the above code just as a challenge for my proficiency in C. Specifically, the low level aspects of C such as character handling (notice bit manipulation ?). If you're suggesting higher level languages just for the sake of their simplicity and syntactic sugar, C is more familiar to me than Java, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quite like it. 
It's got a reasonable structure and names.

I haven't see functions declared in this style:

```
static Winner who_won(brd, player1, player2)
    Board *brd;
    Player *player1, *player2;
{
```

in many a year. They've been obsolete for 25 years. You're very strongly discouraged from using them in new code.

Use the modern prototype-style instead:

```
static Winner who_won(Board *brd, Player *player1, Player *player2){
```

You've used enumerations which is good.

The line

```
 count += !!(*brd)[x][y];
```

is a little obscure. How about

```
count += ((*brd)[x][y])==NONE?0:1;
```

If you haven't encountered 'inline if' it's time to learn it.

Comment: "You're very strongly discouraged from using them in new code."

What should be used instead?

Comment: @confused00: 
`static Winner who_won(Board *brd, Player *player1, Player *player2);`

As opposed the style in the OP where the types are declared after the `)` and before the `{`. It was considered old-school when I learned 'C' in the late 80s.

Comment: Concerning the old style, I actually think that style to be more readable and cleaner (clearer ?) than the newer style. As for `!!(*brd)[x][y]`, I do know about 'inline Ifs' and I've used them **a lot**. For the specific purpose of this line, I think using double negation [will work fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617090/double-negation-in-c-is-it-guaranteed-to-return-0-1) ...

Comment: Amr Ayman, The prototype style isn't considered a matter of style. The C committee declared it obsolete in 1989. The committee positively discourages compiler implementers and coders from supporting/using them. It's 25 years later.... 
PS: Their weakness is the parameter names appear twice so you have a maintenance overhead before you start. You can always lay out the prototype in a similar style.

  
Double negative 'washing' will work fine. But is that really the most readable code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks very clean, very nice overall. Personal preference is the always bracketed approach, however. Even on single line `if` statements, I believe brackets should be used. I've seen people debug a code for an hour or more just because they should have had an enclosed bracket below their if statement, but instead just executed the first line.

```
 if (select_menu( (const char *[]) { "User", "Computer" }, 2, "> " ))
        player2.type = COMP;
```

to

```
 if (select_menu( (const char *[]) { "User", "Computer" }, 2, "> " )) {
        player2.type = COMP;
 }
```

I know it takes up an extra line, but to me the readability it just so much better.